# Normalizing a Definite Integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Say I have a function $f(x)$ that fulfills the following normalization condition:

$\frac{1}{360}\int^{360}_0f(x)dx = 1$

Now say I have a new function $g(x)$ that I want to integrate over a different range: [-180, 180].  If I want this new function's integral to fulfill the same normalization condition as that for $f(x)$, is it still appropriate to use $\frac{1}{360}$ as the constant by which the integral is multiplied, as in

$\frac{1}{360}\int^{180}_{-180}g(x)dx = 1$?

Or does this new range demand a new normalization constant?

I believe the normalization constant should be the same, because I think the appropriate way to normalize is with a constant defined as follows:

$\frac{1}{a-b}$, where a is the upper limit of the integral and b is the lower limit.

Comment: What is the relation between $f$ and $g$?

Comment: In my case they're both Gaussians, but in this question I'm interested in how integrals in general are normalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no deep relationship between $f$ and $g$, then there is no reason why the same normalization constant should hold. For instance, consider the function $h(x) = 2$. Then
$$ \int_{-180}^{180} h(x) dx = 720,$$
and dividing by $360$ will not give $1$. The normalization constant says much more about the function than the interval.

Comment: Right.  Hmm.  In my case the functions are Gaussians.  What I'm trying to do is tweak the parameters of $f(x)$ such that the new function is normalized (in the same way) over the range [-180, 180].  But before I tweak parameters, I'm trying to determine what it means to be normalized over that range.